# Combination subset size for a string with varying constraints given a specific Hamming distance

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to determine the number of possible combinations for a string where sections of the string have different ranges and some need to be in arrangement (can't be same as previous number).

For additional context, this string represents an (N, K) system. N is the number of nodes and K is the number of connections to other nodes. A node can be connected to itself and the number of connections is less than the number of nodes (`0<K<N`) but it can't be connected twice to the same node (no redundancy). The order of the connection matters.

As an example, with a (3,2) system, we have 3 nodes (A, B and C) that will each have 2 connections. The possible arrangements for any given node would be: {A,B},{B,A},{A,C},{C,A},{B,C} and {C,B}, for a total of 6 possible arrangement.

Now comes the tricky part: Each node acts as a digital gate with an associated truth table. Using binary notation, a node with 2 connections will have a truth table with 4 ($2^K$) entries, like this:

| Input 1 | Input 2 | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | X |
| 0 | 1 | X |
| 1 | 0 | X |
| 1 | 1 | X |

where the output value can either be 0 or 1. One instance of a node could be written like this:

AB0001

since there is a total of 3 nodes, the entire system can be written by appending each string together:

AB0001BC1010AC1101

Easier to read with some spacing:

AB 0001 BC 1010 AC 1101

I think I know how to compute the total possible combinations: It would be $96^N$, where 96 comes from multiplying the number of arrangements of inputs for a node ($N!/(N-K)!$) with the combination of outputs for a node ($2^{2^K}$).

But what I want to compute is a subset of that: the number of possible combinations given a specific Hamming distance. To clarify, these would be valid string if using a distance of 2

AB 0001 BC ***01***10 AC 1101

AB 0001 ***AB*** 1010 AC 1101

***C***B 0001 BC 1010 AC 11***1***1

AB 0***1***01 BC 1010 ***B***C 1101

This is the closest I was able to find on the site, but doesn't fit my problem:
[Find the number of rearrangements of the string 12345 in which none of the sequences 12, 23, 34, 45 occur](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148942/find-the-number-of-rearrangements-of-the-string-12345-in-which-none-of-the-seque)